# Variable in string containing SQL query - Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a string set up the following way:

```
sql_string = ( """ select * from schema.table where column1 like '%object%' and column2 = '%s' """)%(x)
```

Unfortunately when I run my script, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Is there any way for me to have a variable in my query string? I suspect that the percent signs in the column1 section of the query are what is causing issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use format function:

```
sql_string = ( """ select * from schema.table where column1 like '%object%' and column2 = '{}' """).format(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the % using an other %:

```
sql_string = ( """ select * from schema.table where column1 like '%%object%%' and column2 = '%s' """)%(x)
```